# Linux kernel regression on power usage

Tags: kernel, power-management

[Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/linux-kernel-power-issue-fix.html#more) reported this power management fix for the 2.6.38 Linux kernel regression:

Add the following to the boot grub line `"pcie_aspm=force"`

My question - how does this suggested fix differ from this hint from powertop:

**Suggestion:** Enable Device Power Management by pressing the P key, which execute the following action:

`find /sys/devices/pci* -path "*power/control" -exec bash -c "echo auto > '{}'" \;`

Comment: Where is the question? If have an answer for your own question, just add the answer below.

Comment: OK the question is do both measures do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power management regression you are referring to was actually the Linux kernel learning to respect the BIOS when it says "these devices don't support PCIe ASPM".  Now, sometimes (often!) the BIOS is wrong about this, but should your system start to randomly hang after forcing this option on, one candidate is that you've force-enabled a broken hardware feature.

- You can help test the fix by going to this [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement).