# How do I solve this super 11.10 heating problem

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux kernel regression on power usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50980/linux-kernel-regression-on-power-usage)

I just installed 11.10 64bit on my Win 7 laptop but instantly i realized how hot the laptop become when i run Ubuntu. I sometimes have to boot into Windows just to cool down the laptop.

I read this was a common problem with 11.10 and that there is kernel bug( like i said i read from somewhere)

How do I solve this heating problem as clearly it has nothing to do with hardware as Windows 7 runs quite cool but 11.10 always give a massive temperature hike (not less than 55 degrees)

My Rig:
HP Pavilion DV 6700
Win 7/11.10 64 bit dual boot
Intel 965/ x3100
Intel Core Duo 2.0 Ghz
4gb RAM

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a solution. My laptop is running EXTREMELY hot under Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: I am now stuck with Windows 7 as i just can't use this in such a state please Canonical FIX IT. I had wanted to show Ubuntu ro my friends. But not in this state

Comment: ATI graphics card?

Comment: No intel 965, Ubuntu has always being quiet but 11.10 is so different with this heating problem

Comment: Same here. I just ended up using Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu 10.10). Problem occurs from Linux kernel version 2.6.37 and will eventually kill the laptop battery, or at least that's what happened to me. Could you mark this bug report as "Affecting you"? The more people are affected, the higher the bug's priority. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/858916

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Aha my favorite helper Jorge Castro. I will do that